# Can you clear the mail object after send for bulk email?

Tags: php, laravel, email

Using Laravel 8.0 - I am sending many email using a job queue. Here is the basic code:

```
Log::debug('EmailJob.php - memory allocation before loop: ' . round(memory_get_usage()/1048576, 1).'mb');
foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
   try {
       Mail::to($contact)->send(new EmailNotify($contact));
   } catch (\Exception $e) {
       $results = $e->getMessage();
   }
}
Log::debug('EmailJob.php - memory allocation after loop: ' . round(memory_get_usage()/1048576, 1).'mb');
```

Here is my log on collecting `memory_get_usage()` before and after sending 3500 email (about 45.8kb each):

```
[2020-12-21 19:01:08] local.DEBUG: EmailJob.php - memory allocation before loop: 23.1mb  
[2020-12-21 19:25:30] local.DEBUG: EmailJob.php - memory allocation after loop: 241.3mb
```

I tried setting the Mail object to a variable, then setting it to null after send, but this failed (I believe because it set the object to null before the send was complete).

The growing memory allocation forces me to limit my batches of email or greatly increase limits. This just doesn't seem like an efficient way to run this.

EDIT: Added log code so it's clear where I'm collecting memory allocation. Note that this code is inside of a Laravel Job that is executed through a queue worker.

EDIT2: This code is inside of a Laravel Job that implements ShouldQueue (see Laravel Mail). The job is executed by a queue worker `php artisan queue:work`, so this code is run as a single job but $contacts has many records. The Mail class is called synchronously in the foreach loop as you can see, but I believe `Mail::send` returns control before it receives a response from the mail server and thus retains memory and effectively means code is running asynchronously. If so, my question is: is there a way to know when `Mail::send` is done and then can you free the allocated memory for that single send (kind of like a manual garbage collection or maybe somehow using `gc_collect_cycles()`).

Comment: What if you send them to the queue worker? In your job, that actually sends the email in the queue, make sure you add `public function __destruct() {}` the clear memory. 3500 emails will take a while, but it will be eventually done.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey See my edit. Also, I don't think that function_desctruct() will help in this case since destroying the function would only occur after the job is finished.

Comment: Are these mails sent synchronously, or on finishing the process?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm not sure I understand your question. See my Edit2.

Comment: you could optimize memory by converting your `foreach` to a `for` and unsetting each `$contacts[<idx>]` after each iteration

Comment: @james This was a good thought (I tried it), but apparently time is needed to complete Mail::send and variable clears before it completes causing it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

**If** mails are sent out asynchronously, this happens on finishing the process. While the process is running, these mails are stored in the memory, that's why the used memory is that high within the process. As you can see in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#queueing-by-default), that's what you've configured through that `ShouldQueue` interface.

If you don't want to queue the mails, remove that interface and mails are sent out directly. This could lead to less memory used, as the mails are not stored anywhere in the meantime.

---

Putting this aside: it's unclear whether this could help to resolve the problem. This depends on the internals of Laravel's mail implementation. If you want to achieve a more safe system (meaning: more control over which mails are really sent out without triggering any memory limit exceptions), queue the mails on your own. This could be achieved through something like a database table that is filled with all recipients in one process, which is afterwards read and processed in small chunks by another process